# ValueError: n_splits=3 cannot be greater than the number of members in each class

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am getting an error:

`ValueError: n_splits=3 cannot be greater than the number of members in each class.`

In this line:

```
gs_clf_svm = gs_clf_svm.fit(X, y)

y.shape
Out[148]: (6,)

y
Out[149]: 
array(['Andheri East', 'Goregaon', 'Powai', 'Andheri East', 'Goregaon',
       'Powai'], dtype=object)
```

In the above line is details of data and shape details. Please suggest

Comment: What does X look like? It seems likely that is where the problem is. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/39824687/9742036

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have  only 2 members per unique class for the your target. Try set `n_splits` equal 2 for `GridSearchCV`. Or increase your dataset.