# ValueError: k-fold cross-validation requires at least one train/test split by setting n_splits=2 or more, got n_splits=1

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am getting the error

```
ValueError: k-fold cross-validation requires at least one train/test split by setting n_splits=2 or more, got n_splits=1
```

same question available [ValueError: Cannot have number of splits n_splits=3 greater than the number of samples: 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39824600/valueerror-cannot-have-number-of-splits-n-splits-3-greater-than-the-number-of-s)

for me

I used python 3.8.6 with scikit-learn==0.23.2, everything worked fine,

I updated to python 3.9.5 with scikit-learn==0.24.2, got this error, i have 191 samples in X_test. I am unsure why library version causing this issue.

Using cv=3 with total 1000 records dataset

Full Code

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features,
                                                    labels,
                                                    test_size=0.2,
                                                    random_state=200)
smote_enn = SMOTEENN(sampling_strategy='all', random_state=127)
X_train_senn, y_train_senn = smote_enn.fit_resample(X_train, y_train)
lgbmclassifier = LGBMClassifier(boosting_type='gbdt',
                                max_depth=-1,
                                device_type=deviceType,
                                verbose=0,
                                objective='binary',
                                class_weight='balanced',
                                force_row_wise=True,
                                subsample_for_bin=200000,
                                min_child_samples=20,
                                random_state=50)
lgbmgrid = CVGrid(lgbmclassifier, FE_Hyperparamerters)
lgbmgrid_result = lgbmgrid.fit(X_train,
                               y_train,
                               eval_metric='auc',
                               eval_set=[(X_test, y_test)],
                               early_stopping_rounds=ESR,
                               verbose=1)
```

Error

```
 File "C:\prg\utils.py", line 851, in feHPTuning
    lgbmgrid_result = lgbmgrid.fit(X_train,
  File "C:\Users\prg\Anaconda3\envs\automl_py395elk7120_2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 63, in inner_f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\prg\Anaconda3\envs\automl_py395elk7120_2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py", line 762, in fit
    cv_orig = check_cv(self.cv, y, classifier=is_classifier(estimator))
  File "C:\Users\prg\Anaconda3\envs\automl_py395elk7120_2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 63, in inner_f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\prg\Anaconda3\envs\automl_py395elk7120_2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py", line 2062, in check_cv
    return StratifiedKFold(cv)
  File "C:\Users\prg\Anaconda3\envs\automl_py395elk7120_2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 63, in inner_f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\prg\Anaconda3\envs\automl_py395elk7120_2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py", line 636, in __init__
    super().__init__(n_splits=n_splits, shuffle=shuffle,
  File "C:\Users\prg\Anaconda3\envs\automl_py395elk7120_2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 63, in inner_f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\prg\Anaconda3\envs\automl_py395elk7120_2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py", line 280, in __init__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: k-fold cross-validation requires at least one train/test split by setting n_splits=2 or more, got n_splits=1.
```

fit function creates the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is pretty straightforward. You cannot perform a `Kfold` split with only 1 split.

The [Kfold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html) documentation states that `n_splits` is the number of folds and must be at least 2.

If you want to perform only a single split you should use `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split`.

Comment: yes, I understood that, but how its working in 3.8.6, but not in 3.9.5

Comment: I think that sklearn fixed that in the version `0.24.x`.

Comment: sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split this still having the error

Comment: Could you edit the question with the code you used and the respective error?

Comment: for SMOTEENN, fit_sample changed to fit_resample in new updated version

Comment: CVGrid function used the old version of sklearn, that why the error raised, thanks for your help, since the function are in docker some funtions did use the updated versions